# Saving Form Fields into more than one Table

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form in my application .That form asks for data which is meant for two different tables of my Database.

Example
i have two tables Job and Customer,I ask for customers information like name ,email,phone number and i also ask for an starting time.This starting time field is meant for the Job table.

I was thinking to have two forms with two different actions and both actions being mapped to different action classes.But then i thought this would not be a good idea as i will have two different buttons to submit .

How can i map one action to two different action classes .

Here is what i was thinking

```
<s:form action="action1">
        <s:textfield name="field1" label="name" />
        <s:textfield name="field2" label="email" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
<s:form action="action2">
            <s:textfield name="field1" label="startingtime" />
            <s:submit />
        </s:form>
```

and action1 and action2 will be mapped to two different action classes in the controller(xml file).

what i want is

```
<s:form action="anaction">
            <s:textfield name="field1" label="name" />
            <s:textfield name="field2" label="email" />
                <s:textfield name="field1" label="startingtime" />
            <s:submit />
        </s:form>
```

and this action be mapped to two different classes in the xml file

EDIT:I know the following is wrong,how do i achive something like this in the correct way

```
<action name="anaction" class="com.codinghazard.actions.Actionclass" class="com.codinghazard.actions.anotherActionclass">
         <result name="success">pages/success.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">pages/failure.jsp</result>
      </action>
```

i want a single form to post data to two different tables .How do i achieve that?
I have googled and i was not able to find an answer due the fact that i was not able to search correctly (what to search for).

I am using struts2 framework.Please dont downvote.I am a begginer and this is my first framework.

Comment: Database tables and forms/actions are unrelated. Submit a form to your struts action, then insert the submitted data into your two tables. Struts is a presentation layer framework. It doesn't care what you do with the data submitted to its actions. You can write them in one table, 5 tables, a NoSQL database, a file, an email, or whatever.

Comment: I don't understand, don't you know how to write an action implementation? Also accept and upvote previous answers where you got helped.

Comment: i know how actions are implemented.How do i get the data submited from the form into two tables.Of what i know one one class can be mapped for a table.one class can not submit data to two differnt tables.there has to be another class for another table.Am i wrong?

Comment: I don't know until you post the code you have written, probably you are, but what you know is correct. You cannot use multiple classes in the action config.

Comment: thats what i am asking,maybe i ask the right question(my communication skill are poor).

Comment: Now do you want to explain to you why you cannot do that? But it's a different question I asked you.

Comment: i dont know why i cant be done,but it seems illogical to me though.and i tried to chain the action to another action .is that the right approach?

Comment: i would like to know why i cant be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this using Chain Result type. In this after execution of one action, another action will be executed  sequentially.

```
<action name="anaction" class="com.codinghazard.actions.Actionclass">
         <result name="success" type="chain">anotherAction</result>
         <result name="error">pages/failure.jsp</result>
      </action>

<action name="anotherAction" class="com.codinghazard.actions.anotherActionclass">
         <result name="success">pages/success.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">pages/failure.jsp</result>
      </action>
```

You should refer this link

[a link]http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-action-chaining-example/

Comment: i did exactly the same thing ,and learned it from this very tutorial.thanks for the answer anyway